# Verbose log abbriviations meaning in SVC, scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, verbose

I am looking for the meaning of verbose log abbriviations of SVC function in scikit-learn?

If nSV is the number of support vectors, #iter is the number of iteration, what dose nBSV, rho,obj mean?

This is an example:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.svm import SVR
sets=np.loadtxt('data\Exp Rot.txt')         # reading data
model=SVR(kernel='rbf',C=100,gamma=1,max_iter=100000,verbose=True)
model.fit(sets[:,:2],sets[:,2])
print(model.score)
```

and here is the result

[image: this is the verbose log in console]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

scikit-learn is using [libsvm's](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/) implementation of support-vector machines (LinearSVC will use [liblinear](https://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/liblinear/) by the same authors).
The official website has it's own FAQ answering this [here](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/libsvm/faq.html).

Excerpt:

> Q: The output of training C-SVM is like the following. What do they mean?
>
> optimization finished, #iter = 219
>
> nu = 0.431030
>
> obj = -100.877286, rho = 0.424632
>
> nSV = 132, nBSV = 107
>
> Total nSV = 132
>
> obj is the optimal objective value of the dual SVM problem
>
> rho is the bias term in the decision function sgn(w^Tx - rho)
>
> nSV and nBSV are number of support vectors and bounded support vectors (i.e., alpha_i = C)
>
> nu-svm is a somewhat equivalent form of C-SVM where C is replaced by nu
>
> nu simply shows the corresponding parameter. More details are in libsvm document

[Link to the libsvm document mentioned above (PDF!)](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/%7Ecjlin/papers/libsvm.pdf)

Comment: Thank you very much